# What would happen if I transported 100+ items that a business owns for them

Tags: international, travel, customs-law

Let's suppose that I am going on a trip and a friend of mine who owns a business asks me to take in my luggage 100+ items such as clothing/tech. He sold these items in the country I am travelling to, can I deliver these for my friend?

- Is it illegal?
- Would I get the items taken way?
- Or would I be taxed in some way?

EDIT:

A more specific example my friend in China sells 100 laptops and asks me to take 10 of those to America so the customer can recieve them should I pay a VAT duty tax or something of the sort if the sale has already been made.

What is instead of 10 I transported the 100 laptops

Comment: The question at it is stated is too general to answer. You'd need at least the origin/destination country, the country of origin of the products, the type of products, the quantity of products ("item" is not a unit, at least not with an unspecified product) to even begin to look into this.

Comment: Dupe https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/166100/what-happens-if-i-bring-100-of-the-same-item-with-the-intention-of-selling-in-m

Comment: yeah that was my question and I was adviced to ask in Law Stack Exchange (also perfumes was a bad example) What I need to know is if after the sale has been made I have to pay some tax (also what tax) just for taking it in my luggage

Comment: In principle a country can levy taxes / duties / tariffs on whatever they choose, and it is not always easy to know in advance what it will be; the rules can be complex and change frequently. The US's [current tariff rules](https://hts.usitc.gov/view/finalCopy?release=2021HTSABasicRev3) are 4300 pages long.  And of course, the amount of the tax might make a difference between this venture being profitable or not.

Answer (score 1):

In general, items that are of value must be declared at customs when bringing them into a country, particularly items being brought in for sale or delivered after a sale. Failure to declare such items is a crime in many countries. Exactly what must be declared varies.

If items are declared there is likely to be an import tax depending on the items, their value, and the laws o the destination country.

If they are not declared and this is discovered, there may be fines and penalties, and possibly jail time or prison. The imported items may be seized. Again the laws of the destination country will control all this.

Comment: Also, your visa would likely be invalid and you would be denied admission or you would risk deportation if you had, e.g., a tourist visa and brought these goods with you which would as a matter of law make it a business trip for a sales or shipping purpose.